# How to Read Excel file Uploaded to database without saving the excel to the server using

Tags: c#, excel

I have written a code which uploads an excel sheet to the server database. Till uploading it works fine. But my requirement is now to read the excel sheet data from the uploaded file which is already there on the database without downloading it to the server?

```
byte[] tempContent = GetImage(Name); 
MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream(); 
test.Write(tempContent, 0, tempContent.Length); 
HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook(test);
```

The last line errors out "Null Reference Exception was Caught"

The function GetImage(Name) gets the data from the uploaded excel file after matching the file name on the db

Comment: i'm not quite sure i understand what 'downloading it to the server' means.  but perhaps it doesnt matter.  In order to open an excel file, it has to be in memory of the machine viewing it.  That means pulling it do the machine. You could delete it right after i suppose, but it has to be on the machine.

Comment: The application will be uploaded to the web server now my problem is that i don't want to save the excel to the server's hard disk. I want to simply read the data from the excel which is saved in the database?

Comment: Its stored as a blob in the db?

Comment: Yes it is stored as a blob in the db

Comment: Well, having gone down that road, i can tell you that while it seems good now, you'll have problems in the future.  That said... have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I am using a memory stream to get the data from the database but my code fails at a point where i am using HSSFWorkbook wb = HSSFWorkbook(test);
where test is the memory stream.
BTW in the above code i have used NPOI

Comment: Then THAT should be your question.  Post the code you've written and the error you are getting.

Comment: byte[] tempContent = GetImage(Name);
MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream();
test.Write(tempContent, 0, tempContent.Length);
HSSFWorkbook wb1 = new HSSFWorkbook(test);
The last line errors out "Null Reference Exception was Caught"

Comment: That code would look better in your question.. along w/ what GetImage(Name) does and the error you get when it fails.

Comment: GetImage(Name) is the function used to get the data from the database depending on the filename which we pass through the code.

Comment: Solved the problem. Actually the problem was with the xls file. Thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the .xls file. Opened and saved it again and it started working. The code worked perfectly.